# Physically Based Rendering Results Don't Look Correct

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, pbr

I've been trying to implement physically based rendering using the following [resource](http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/s2013-shading-course/karis/s2013_pbs_epic_notes_v2.pdf). It describes equations one could use to implement physically based shading. Here is my shader code:

```
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

#ifdef SHADER_VERTEX

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 Position;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
    Position = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0));
    Normal = vec3(model * vec4(normal, 0.0));
}

#endif

#ifdef SHADER_FRAGMENT

in vec3 Position;
in vec3 Normal;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform float roughness;
uniform vec3 specularColor;

vec3 D(vec3 normal, vec3 h)
{
    float a2 = roughness * roughness * roughness * roughness;
    float NdotH = dot(normal, h);
    float x = (NdotH * NdotH) * (a2 - 1) + 1;
    return vec3(a2 / (M_PI * (x * x)));
}

vec3 G1(vec3 normal, vec3 v)
{
    float k = ((roughness + 1) * (roughness + 1)) / 8.0f;
    float NdotV = dot(normal, v);

    return vec3(NdotV / ((NdotV * (1 - k) + k)));
}

vec3 G(vec3 normal, vec3 l, vec3 v)
{
    return G1(normal, l) * G1(normal, v);
}

vec3 F(vec3 v, vec3 h)
{
    vec3 f0 = specularColor;
    float VdotH = dot(v, h);
    float exponent = (-5.55473 * VdotH - 6.98316) * VdotH;
    return vec3(f0 + ((vec3(1, 1, 1) - f0) * pow(2, exponent)));
}

vec3 specular(vec3 n, vec3 l, vec3 h, vec3 v)
{
    float NdotL = dot(n, l);
    float NdotV = dot(n, v);
    return (D(n, h) * F(v, h) * G(n, l, v)) / ((4 * NdotL * NdotV));
}

vec3 diffuse(vec3 normal, vec3 lightDir)
{
    float NdotL = dot(normal, lightDir);
    vec3 result = objectColor / M_PI;
    return result * NdotL;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - Position);
    vec3 eyeVector = normalize(cameraPos - Position);
    vec3 halfVector = normalize(lightDir + eyeVector);

    color = vec4(diffuse(norm, lightDir) + specular(norm, lightDir, halfVector, eyeVector), 1.0);
}

#endif
```

Here are the results: [image]

As you can see, there is a weird white band in the middle. The light position is  above the sphere and the camera is in front of the sphere. The roughness variable is currently set to 0.2. I don't know if I implemented the equations wrong or what it is supposed to look like with the parameters I passed in.

Comment: It looks like your code is counting on `M_PI` having the same value as π.  It resembles a seam, from rounding.

Comment: How can I fix this issue? I did not think there would be an issue due to rounding. Is there a problem with the way I used the equations? I tried using the max function on all dot products to ensure the number is non negative and it appears to have gotten rid of the white band, but I don't know if this is mathematically correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** What happens when `n` is perpendicular to `l`?

```
vec3 specular(vec3 n, vec3 l, vec3 h, vec3 v)
{
    float NdotL = dot(n, l);
    float NdotV = dot(n, v);
    return (D(n, h) * F(v, h) * G(n, l, v)) / ((4 * NdotL * NdotV));
}
```

**A:** This function will return 0/0, except instead of 0 there will be rounding errors, so you could end up with anything.

You'll need to rearrange the equation so you don't end up with 0/0 anywhere.

Comment: I see. I changed it so that I add a really small value to the denominator so that it will never divide by 0 and the results are better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Won't that fail if the denominator is slightly negative?

Comment: I made the dot products never be negative by using the max function so the denominator should never be negative. I assumed that those dot products were never supposed to be negative anyways. I don't know if that is correct though.

Comment: The dot product of two unit vectors will be in the range -1...+1, so negative results are entirely normal.  +1 when the vectors are the same, 0 when they are at right angles, and -1 when the vectors point in the opposite direction.

Comment: But in terms of lighting, if the dot product is negative, then the light will be behind the triangles. Also, a negative color doesn't make sense so I would assume you would just disregard negative numbers.

Comment: The light *is* behind the triangles that are on the bottom.  The dot product `dot(lightDir, normal)` is positive for the triangles on the top of the sphere, and negative for triangles on the bottom.  The place where it crosses from positive to negative is the seam in your picture.

Comment: Yes but this dot product is used in calculating the color. If it is negative then you get a negative color and that doesn't make sense, so don't you want to set it to zero when it is negative?

Comment: It will only result in a negative color if the numerator is also negative.  Notice that `dot(lightDir, normal)` also appears in the numerator.

Comment: I have found another paper, [link](http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/s2013-shading-course/hoffman/s2013_pbs_physics_math_notes.pdf), that mentions to clamp the dot product to zero and add a really small value like I have previously mentioned since the equations I am using are not valid when the dot product is negative. It seems like this is the solution to negative numbers